# Convert/wrap Spacy model into a Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, spacy-3, kubeflow-pipelines, mlops

Is it possible to convert a saved spacy model into a TensorFlow model? Spacy provides a wrapper to work with TensorFlow models. Mentioned [here](https://spacy.io/usage/layers-architectures#frameworks).

Can this be done the other way around? I need to convert a Spacy model into a TensorFlow model or wrap it up in that way so that it can be deployed with TensorFlow Serving or other frameworks like Kserve which provide plugins for TensorFlow.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I can't find a good way of serving Spacy models.